# Telerik Grid ASP.NET MVC 2.0 Selectable Issue

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2, asp.net-mvc-areas, telerik-grid

I am trying to use a telerik grid in my view which is located in an administration area.
Currently when I create views in the root level and use telerik grids, the grid properties such as, selectable(), work fine. When I do this in my administration area, the grid is rendered but the properties (such as .selectable()) do not work. I believe it is a referencing issue as my telerik scripts are located in the root level of the project in a 'scripts' folder and the corresponding css is located in the root level as well under a 'content' folder. The following is a snippet of my broken code:

```
  <% Html.Telerik().Grid<Ability>()
       .Name("Role Abilities Grid")
       .BindTo((IEnumerable<Ability>) Model)
       .DataKeys(k => k.Add(a => a.AbilityId))
       .Columns(c => 
        { 
            c.Bound(a => a.AbilityId).Width(45);
        })
       .Scrollable( scroll => scroll.Enabled(true))
       .Selectable()
       .Render(); 
        Html.Telerik().ScriptRegistrar()  %>
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok Here's what was wrong, the grid .Name contained white spaces and needed to be space-less

```
  <% Html.Telerik().Grid<Ability>()
   .Name("RoleAbilitiesGrid")
   .BindTo((IEnumerable<Ability>) Model)
   .DataKeys(k => k.Add(a => a.AbilityId))
   .Columns(c => 
    { 
        c.Bound(a => a.AbilityId).Width(45);
    })
   .Scrollable( scroll => scroll.Enabled(true))
   .Selectable()
   .Render(); 
    Html.Telerik().ScriptRegistrar()  %>
```

Now it works correctly!